# My greedy fractional knapsack algorithm fails in a test case where i don't know the input

Tags: java, algorithm

Task: Implement an algorithm for the fractional knapsack problem.

Input:The first line of the input contains the number n of items and the capacity W of a knapsack.The next n lines define the values and weights of the items. The n-th line contains integers v(i-th)and w(i-th) - values and weights.

Output:The  maximal value of fractions of items that fit into the knapsack. The absolute value of the difference between result of and the optimal value should be at most 10 power -3.

My Problem: The test tool gives me error "wrong output:list in index out of range

What i've tried: I compared the result my code with 10 manual test cases, worked fine. Couldn't produce an input that leads to outOfBounds problem .

My code:

```
public class FractionKnapsack {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int capacity = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] values = new int[n];
        int[] weights = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            weights[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> order = bestItem(values,weights,n);
        System.out.println(getOptimalValue(capacity, values, weights,n,order));
    }


 public static ArrayList<Integer> bestItem(int[] values, int[] weights, int n){

        ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<>();
        order.add(0);
        if (n>1){
            if (values[1]/(double) weights[1] >= values[0]/(double) weights[0]){
                order.add(0, 1);
            }
            else
                order.add(1);

            for (int i =2;i < n;i++){
                double relationOfItem =  values[i]/(double) weights[i];
                boolean found = false;
                int count = 0;
                while (!found){
                    if (count == n-1){
                        found = true;
                        order.add(i);
                    }else {
                        double relationToCompare = values[order.get(count)]/(double) weights[order.get(count)];
                        if (relationOfItem >= relationToCompare){
                            order.add(count, i );
                            found = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return order;
        }
        return order;

    }

    private static double getOptimalValue(int capacity, int[] values, int[] weights, int n, ArrayList<Integer> order) {
        double value = 0;
        int[] amounts = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n;i++){
            if (capacity == 0)
                return value;

            if (capacity >= weights[order.get(i)]){
                value+=values[order.get(i)];
                capacity-=weights[order.get(i)];
            }
            else{
                double fraction = (double) capacity/ weights[order.get(i)];
                //System.out.println("fraction: "+fraction);
                //System.out.println("capacity: " + capacity);
                //System.out.println("weight: " + weights[order.get(i)]);
                value+= fraction*values[order.get(i)];
                capacity = 0;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: where exactly are you getting this problem?

Comment: This comes from a site like hackerRank, right ? And one of the test fails but you can't know which one, because they don't give it to you ?

Comment: I can't answer that because the only thing i know is that the test tool gives me "wrong output format: list index out of range". I guess it must be in the loop in `getOptimalValue()` where i access the list.

Comment: Asoub, right. There are some test cases where i know the input, these one are correct. One of the other fails

Comment: Have you tried throwing a custom exception and see if the site somehow returns its message ?